# Ubuntu 12.04 Issue with Multi-Drive USB Enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, ubuntu-12.04, usb

I have an Addonics multi-drive enclosure using an AD5HPMREU controller to connect it via USB to a server, which is running Ubuntu 12.04.

This very same enclosure, with the same cable, connects flawlessly to a laptop which dual-boots Win7 and Ubuntu 12.10 (live cd).

However, on the 12.04 box, no go.  I get a bunch of this:

```
usb 2-1.7: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
usb 2-1.7: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-1.7: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-1.7: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 2-1.7: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-1.7: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-1.7: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
usb 2-1.7: device not accepting address 11, error -32
usb 2-1.7: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
usb 2-1.7: device not accepting address 12, error -32
hub 2-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 7
```

I have also tried booting this server off the same live cd to see if it was 12.04 vs 12.10 issue, but it made no difference.  I've removed all other USB devices from the system - no difference.

I've seen lots of references to *similar* issues, but nothing which matches:

```
device not accepting address 12, error -32
```

(specifically the -32 part)

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns-out, the controller card appears to have just up and gone bad.  Replaced it with a new one and everything works as expected.

Comment: You should flag this as solved @Michael. You'l get reward for it and it looks better. Cheers.